# htaccess - how to set preferred URL correctly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've got a website that visitors are accessing through several different link formats. E.G.

- www.website.com
- http://www.website.com
- website.com/index.php
- http://www.website.com/index.php

But I just want to redirect everyone to access from http://www.website.com as the preferred URL.

I have tried on htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.website.com/
```

But getting:

- The page isn't redirecting properly
- This webpage has a redirect loop

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule for this redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.website.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly!